# I'm getting this error when I try to put Image in GridView1. Please can anyone help me resolve it

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, web

DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ImageName'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ImageName'.

Source Error:

Line 233:                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Photo">
Line 234:                    
Line 235:                         <img src="Images/Product Images/<%# Eval("PID") %>/<%# Eval("ImageName") %><%# Eval("Extention") %>" alt="<%# Eval("ImageName") %>" style=" height:150px; width:150px;"/> --%>
Line 236:                    
Line 237:                </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: Show your data binding code, show what you are data binding with.

Comment: Error seems clear. There is no `ImageName` present in the dataset you are binding to the GridView...